# How can i pass data from ReactJS submit form to AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, adonis.js

I have a form in ReactJS and every time i click the submit button, the data should pass to adonis api.

ReactJs file

```
  async handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
      await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/add',
          data: JSON.stringify(this.state),
      })
          .then(function (response) {
                console.log('response',response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error',error);
            });

    }
```

"http://127.0.0.1:3333/add" is Adonis server with a route '/add'

i don't know how to write in Adonis to post state on that route

Can anybody explain me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a simple controller to handle your data which would receive  from your `handleSubmit()` method in ReactJS app.

Use the below command to create a simple controller:

```
adonis make:controller TestController --type http
```

Once created, open the `TestController` file and make an `index` method and add the followings which are inside the `index` method.

```
'use strict'

class TestController{
  // define your index method here 
 index ({ request }) {
    const body = request.post() // get all the post data;
    console.log(body) //console it to see the passed data
  }
}

module.exports = TestController
```

After that, register your `/add` route in `start/routes.js` file.

```
Route.post('/add', 'TestController.index') // controller name and the method
```

And finally, hit the Submit button in your ReactJS app, and test it.

> Most likely you be getting `CORS issues` when you send the request
>   from your ReactJS app to Adonis server, If so you have to `proxy` the `api` request to Adonis server.

To do that, open up your `package.json` file in ReactJS App, and add the below `proxy field`.

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3333",
```

Answer (score 1):

- in controller's function in get value like this 
  `const data = request.only(['data'])` then you get data.
- other method to get data like this 
  `const alldata = request.all()`
  this console this result and view how many result you get 
  and get data from this `alldata.data`